# NSMutableArray objects are empty after creation

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm a newbie to Objective-C, so please bear with me.

I have a custom object called UpdateData:

```
 @interface UpdateData : NSObject
-(NSString*) getPath;
-(void) setPath:(NSString*) path ;
@end
```

As I create this items from parsing a list:

```
NSMutableArray *serverData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (i = 1; i < [chunks count]; i++) {//chunks contains infor for parsing
    UpdateData *ud = [[UpdateData alloc] init];
    NSString * element = [chunks objectAtIndex:i];
    [ud setPath: element];
    [serverData addObject:ud];
    NSLog(@"Path: %@",[[serverData lastObject] getPath]);
}

NSLog(@"Done parsing! Elements: %lu", [serverData count]);
```

Within that loop, the UpdateData (read straight from the Array) have the values. I get the following output:

```
Path: path
.
.
.
Done parsing! Elements: x
```

Where x is greater than 0 and equal to the objects parsed and path is the correct path parsed.

In the same method I later try to go over the Array to read the values of the objects:

```
for (i = 0; i < [serverData count]; i++) {
        UpdateData *ud = [serverData objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Path: %@",[ud getPath]);
}
```

There the output is:

```
Path:
```

Values are lost. The for loops are back to back, exactly as shown above.

Any ideas?

Update:

The UpdateData class:

```
#import "UpdateData.h"

@implementation UpdateData
NSString* path=@"";

-(NSString*) getPath{
    return path;
}

-(void) setPath:(NSString*) newpath{
    path = newpath;
}
@end
```

Does that initialization there matter? Should be overwritten right?

Comment: What is `getPath` doing? By the way: Getters in Objecive-C don't begin with 'get'.

Comment: The bug seems to be related to your UpdateData class, not the NSMutableArray. Please provide the code of your UpdateData class

Comment: your -getPath is probably crashing/throwing an exception and it exits. Which is probably why you only see the first **Path** in the console output.

Comment: NSLog `ud` itself, to see if it's the type of object you think it is.  Then set a breakpoint in `getPath` to see if you ever get there.  Also set a breakpoint in `setPath` to see if you get there and to see what value you store.  And where in your UpdateData object do you store "path"?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin - I would assume that if getPath were throwing an exception the OP would be complaining about that, and not the lack of data returned.

Comment: getPath just returns a String.

Comment: Returns a string or is supposed to return a string?  *Debug it!*  Find out what's going on!  Learn how to set breakpoints and examine data values.

Comment: (If you don't know how to debug, ask some questions about that.  Yes, you will get razzed a bit, but you will learn something.)

Comment: If getPath was crashing, the following output wouldn't happen. The dots represent other output. Didn't want to flood the post with 1630 outputs.

Comment: You didn't implement setPath()?

Comment: Yes I did. Missed that when pasted.

Comment: What's ARC? I'm coding on Xcode.

Comment: I would really strongly recommend working through some introductory material (tutorials etc.) before doing stuff like this. If you don't even know how your memory is managed, the odds that you are creating innumerable armies of bugs to bite you in the future are absolutely terrifying.

Comment: The issue was a logic issue. I was creating a new object way too often, since only storing an empty object with the last field of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: (untested)

`.h` file:

```
@interface UpdateData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *path;

/*-(NSString*) getPath;*/
-(void) setPath:(NSString*) path ;
@end
```

`.m` file:

```
@interface UpdateData ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *path;
@end

@implementation UpdateData 
/*
-(NSString*) getPath{
    return path;
}*/

-(void) setPath:(NSString*) newpath{
    path = newpath;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `Path` property in the implementation like this:

```
#import "UpdateData.h"

@implementation UpdateData {
    NSString *_path;
}

-(NSString*) getPath{
    return _path;
}

-(void) setPath:(NSString*) newpath{
    _path = newpath;
}
@end
```

Since Xcode handles automatically the getters and setters. If you don't need them for any other internal class purpose. I'd suggest you to use this line only in your `.h` file and remove the getters and setters:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *path;`